# Google Go and SQLite: What library to use and how?

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

I'm fairly new to Google's Go, but I'm trying to learn more by writing a simple application to talk to an SQLite 3 database. So far I've come across a few different sqlite libraries, but they all seem to be sparsely maintained or have little or no documentation.

I was hoping someone here would be able to point me in the right direction by suggesting a library to use for SQLite 3, and giving me some demo code for simple INSERTs and SELECTs.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** relevant also for Go 1.

With a recent go weekly, and an installed Sqlite3 library on a Linux system, you should:

```
$ go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
sqlite3.go: In function ‘_cgo_7e09c699097a_Cfunc_sqlite3_prepare_v2’:
sqlite3.go:198:2: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘sqlite3_prepare_v2’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h:2924:16: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
$ # those warnings are OK, don't worry
$ mkdir $GOPATH/src/myproject && cd $GOPATH/src/myproject
$ wget https://raw.github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/master/example/main.go
$ vi main.go # this is an example how to use go-sqlite3
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

My first advice, for sqlite or other DBMS, is to limit your research to drivers implementing the new database/sql API (available in Go Weekly). It's very clean, efficient, and limit the adherence of your code to the driver.

Regarding SQLite, I've only found this driver (that I don't know) : 
https://github.com/gwenn/gosqlite